# Problem with flash in a webbrowser in a winform

Tags: .net, winforms, flash, webbrowser-control

I have the oddest problem (but aren't all programming problems odd?).  I have a winform that contains a webbrowser object that opens a website that has flash on it.  This winform is running on a touchscreen computer (I can't find the brand or model number).

Here is what I know:

- flash objects embeded in a website that is accessed via the webbrowser object in my winform do not function properly
- said flash objects only react to the first 'click' on them.  So the website opens and if I hit a button, that button works but nothing afterward works within the flash object works.  If my first 'click' misses a button, nothing works there after.
- trying to 'click' an flash button gives the same response as just hovering over the button
- This isn't a problem with the touch part of the touch screen as using a mouse also gives the same not working right response
- this isn't a problem with the web page as I can open up explorer on the same computer and navigate the webpage just fine from there
- The program also works 100% right on my personal computer so it shouldn't be the program's fault
- if it's not the touch screen fault and not the program's fault, I can't blame anything right now.
- the EXACT same program worked 100% on our old touch screen (which was having *other* problems so we had to get rid of it).
- Oh, also, surfing just a 'normal' webpage in a webbrowser in the winform works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar error and the only solution was to ensure that at least service pack 1 for .NET 2.0 was installed on the client machine.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem while developing my windows application.
Create a user defined control as follows:

```
// CREATE A CLASS AND INHERITS TO WEBBROWSER CLASS
public partial class ucWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
     public ucWebBrowser()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
     {
         switch (m.Msg)
         {
            case 0x021:
            case 0x201:
            case 0x204:
            case 0x207:
                base.DefWndProc(ref m);
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Now you can see this control in a Toolbox list. Now click and drag this control on to your winform instead of webbrowser control.